# What's wrong with my Count Query asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

```
Public state_name as String
state_name = Textbox1.Text

Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices").ConnectionString
Dim query As String = "SELECT Count(cities) FROM state_table WHERE state_name=" & state_name
Using conn As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        conn.Open()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = query
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        End With

        Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(comm.ExecuteScalar())
        Label1.Text = count
    End Using
End Using
```

The code shows an error

> Invalid column name 'California'.

But `California` is already present in my `State` table, I want to count all the cities comes under `state_name= california` which I have entered in my `State` table.

I want the output as

```
California (3)
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of concatenating the parameters into your SQL string.

Comment: Add `...state_name='" & state_name &"'" `

Comment: whatever between use the quotes or just add them in your var state_name

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Parameterized Query to avoid [SQL Injection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices").ConnectionString
Dim query As String = "SELECT Count(cities) FROM state_table WHERE state_name=@State_Name"
Using conn As New SqlConnection(constr)
   Using comm As New SqlCommand()
      conn.Open()
      With comm
         .Connection = conn
         .CommandText = query
         .CommandType = CommandType.Text
         .Parameters.AddWithValue("@State_Name", state_name)
      End With
      Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(comm.ExecuteScalar())
      Label1.Text = count
   End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't surround your variable with quotes. `"state_name = '" + state_name + "'"`

But, you should use a parameter instead.